# Django: Error when calling the metaclass bases in Models File

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use social-auth, and following the code in documentation. But, when I run

```
python manage.py convert_to_south
```

I'm getting the following error in my models.py

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

This is my models file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class UsuarioManager(models.Manager):
    def create_user(self, username, email):
        return self.models._default_manager.create(username=username)


class Usuario(models):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UsuarioManager()

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to extend a module with this class is looks like while you may have intended to extend a class in the module:
http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/905168

models.model looks like the the class you want to use: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/

Do your code here would be:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class UsuarioManager(models.Manager):
    def create_user(self, username, email):
        return self.models._default_manager.create(username=username)


class Usuario(models.model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UsuarioManager()

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
```

following the example of:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```